# Dependency issue with Rhythmbox player

Tags: installation, mp3-tag

I want to play mp3 songs in Rhythmbox player but getting issues with dependencies. I provide the two sceenshots of the problem.

[image: dependencies]

[image: unresolved dependencies]

How do I install these dependencies?

Comment: Sorry, we can't view screenshots from your desktop. Could you please upload them using `img` button when you edit your question?

Comment: i didn't know how to include the images; now i have edited the post to include the images.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to install both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions of some plug-ins. Uncheck the packages which have the `:i386` at the end of their names, and you should be fine. I'm not exactly sure why it's suggesting them in that specific place, though.

Comment: i tried without i386 packages, but still getting the same error.